# synchronized tooltips in different charts

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

I have a grid view of 4 fl_charts line charts. At the moment the 4 tooltips works independently, meaning that i only show the tooltip in the chart the mouse is on.

The 4 charts are actually 4 series of the same length and their x axis is actually the same.

What i would like to do is: when i am on a chart, i get the index of the point being hovered and i show the tooltip not only of the graph the nous is on but also on the other 3 graphs corresponding to the datapoint with the same index.

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are structuring the project. You might need to use a state management solution, use a ValueNotifier, or probably if the grid of charts are under the same widget, a StatefulWidget might be enough.

What you'll need to accomplish is to save the position of the cursor hovering the graph, into the state, and when it has a position, you use that position in the other three plots *simulating* the on hover of the cursor.

The same state with the cursor position will be shared by all four graphs, to read and write into.